# order result of eloquent relationship from eloquent relationship too

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm creating feature for order in canteen project. I have made these eloquent relationship:

- canteen->products
- product->canteen
- order->products
- order_product->product (order_product is like detail item of the order)

If I want to get canteen data of the order_product, I can just type order_product->product->canteen->id.

[image]
[image]

This is what I have done to show details of orders. But the lists aren't ordered by the canteen id. So, I want that the eloquent relationship of order->products return products of orders that ordered by canteen_id. Do anyone have solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve it using your current method (or using Eloquent method), because the parent of the object is `OrderProduct` and each of the `Canteen` is inside the `OrderProduct`, so if you apply an order by using Eloquent, it will order it only for each of the `OrderProduct`, not globally. For illustration:

```
{
   order_products: [
      {
         id: 1,
         canteen: {
            id:1
         }
      },
      {
         id: 2,
         canteen: {
            id:3
         }
      },
      {
         id: 3,
         canteen: {
            id:2
         }
      }
   ]
```

If you apply the order by from the format above, it will stay the same because: (1) you only have 1 `Canteen` object, and (2) if you have a one to many relationship to `Canteen`, it will only sort the `Canteen`'s id separately. So, the format that you're looking for might be similar to this:

```
[
   {
      canteen_id: 1,
      order_product_id: 2
   },
   {
      canteen_id: 2,
      order_product_id: 3
   },
   {
      canteen_id: 3,
      order_product_id: 1
   }
]
```

That way, you can sort `Canteen`'s id globally throughout the entire list. There are 2 ways to achieve this. The first one is taking the data from the `Canteen` model, then work your way through `OrderProduct`. Or, you can do it raw query-style, so you can create your own object (which has no more grouping like the Eloquent provides) and order it by `Canteen`'s id.